# Http status 400 Invalid JSON payload received when post data to google text to speech

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

Here is my code using jsoup to post json data

```
  Response resp = Jsoup.connect("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize")
  .header("Authorization", " Bearer "+credential.getAccessToken())
  .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

  .ignoreContentType(true)
  .method(Method.POST)
  .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
  .requestBody("{ \"input\":{ \"text\":\"Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.\" }, \"voice\":{ \"languageCode\":\"en-gb\", \"name\":\"en-GB-Standard-A\", \"ssmlGender\":\"FEMALE\" }, \"audioConfig\":{ \"audioEncoding\":\"MP3\" } }")
  .execute();
```

And here is the error message :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{ \"input\":{ \"text\":\"Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.\" }, \"voice\":{ \"languageCode\":\"en-gb\", \"name\":\"en-GB-Standard-A\", \"ssmlGender\":\"FEMALE\" }, \"audioConfig\":{ \"audioEncoding\":\"MP3\" } }\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{ \"input\":{ \"text\":\"Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{ \"input\":{ \"text\":\"Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.\" }, \"voice\":{ \"languageCode\":\"en-gb\", \"name\":\"en-GB-Standard-A\", \"ssmlGender\":\"FEMALE\" }, \"audioConfig\":{ \"audioEncoding\":\"MP3\" } }\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{ \"input\":{ \"text\":\"Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I think json string not valid, but not, I verify json string, and it valid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue here is in fact related to the JSON that you are posting. Avoid escaping the quotation mark symbol `"` with the backslash `\`. That should resolve your issue. Simply put, the JSON you are posting here should look this way:

> {"input": {"text": "Android is a mobile operating system developed by
>   Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
>   touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets."},"voice":
>   {"languageCode": "en-gb","name": "en-GB-Standard-A", "ssmlGender":
>   "FEMALE"},"audioConfig": {"audioEncoding": "MP3"}}

Comment: I try to paste json content into file and read in to avoid escape character but keep error System.out.println(content);
   Response resp = Jsoup.connect("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize")
   .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+credential.getAccessToken())
   .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
   
   .ignoreContentType(true)
   .method(Method.POST)
   .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
   .requestBody(content)
   .execute();

Comment: I try to replace " by ' but keep happening. I know something very very stupid here but I can't find the reason.

Comment: Perhaps you can try creating a working request using  using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/text%20to%20speech/texttospeech/v1beta1/texttospeech.text.synthesize). Once you get it to work you can compare with your code and implement the necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

### Check HTTP Headers

Ensure you are sending the request with:

> **Content-Type: application/json**